# how to give color, round corner and show to a button

Tags: android, button, shadow, rounded-corners

I want to change the color of a `Button` and give it corner, but my problem is i also want to give it shadow like `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"`, and i am not able to do all these to a `Button`

is anybody knows how to make a `Button` which has different color, be able to change its corner and has shadow behind it?

what i already tried was `Stroke` which did not give me what i want.
i want something like the picture above.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can produce your own button style with a draw-able xml; round, gradient, etc.
I think every thing is self explanatory, but you need to save it to the res/drawable directory.
Give it a name, myroundyellowbutton.xml (for example) and then use it as a background resource in a button or any view which accepts a background.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
        <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#202080" />
        <corners android:radius="10dip" />
        <padding android:left="1dip" android:right="1dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:startColor="#F0e0e0d0" android:endColor="#f0d0d0c0"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#202050" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="2dp" />
    </shape>     
</item>

</selector>
```